# Given that $a<0$, how to compute the limit of $\int_{0}^t e^{a(t-s)}f(s)ds$ when $t\rightarrow{+\infty}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Given that $a<0$, how to prove $I(t):=\int_{0}^t e^{a(t-s)}f(s)ds$ converges to $0$ when $t$ goes to positive infinity?

---

This problem emerged when I tried to determine how the solution(s) of the following ODE converges when $f(t)\rightarrow 0(t\rightarrow +\infty)$:
$$a_0\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+a_1\frac{dx}{dt}+a_2x=f(t).$$

From the theorems I've known about ODE, the solutions are of the form
$$
x=e^{at}\left( c_1\cos b t+c_2\sin b t \right) +\int_0^t{K\left( t-s \right) f\left( s \right) ds}
$$
when the solution of $a_0\lambda^2+a_1\lambda+a_2=0$ are conjugate imaginary, *i.e.*, $\lambda_1=a+bi,\lambda_2=a-bi$,
where $K(t)$ denotes the kernel function
$$
K\left( t \right) =\frac{e^{\lambda _1t}-e^{\lambda _2t}}{\lambda _1-\lambda _2}=\frac{e^{at}\sin bt}{b}.
$$
The first part of solution $e^{at}\left( c_1\cos b t+c_2\sin b t \right)$ obviously converges to $0$ because $\left( c_1\cos b t+c_2\sin b t \right)$ is bounded and $e^{at}$ converges to $0$ when $a<0$.

For the second part $
\int_0^t{}\frac{e^{a\left( t-s \right)}\sin b\left( t-s \right)}{b}f(s)ds$, $\frac{\sin b(t-s)}{b}$ is bounded, so the uncertain part is
$$\int_{0}^t e^{a(t-s)}f(s)ds\xrightarrow{?}0.$$
This is tricky for me because it contains 2 variables and I need to regard $t$ as a parameter primarily, which is beyond my knowledge and capability.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=-a>0$ so that $$I(t)=e^{-At}\int_0^te^{As}f(s)\,ds.$$ L'Hopital yields $$\lim_{t\to\infty}I(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^te^{As}f(s)\,ds}{e^{At}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{At}f(t)}{Ae^{At}}=0$$ as $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! It really helps!

Comment: I've encountered with a similar situation when roots of $a_0\lambda^2+a_1\lambda+a_2=0$ are two same negative real roots, denoted as $\lambda$. Here the problem is $\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)e^{\lambda(t-s)}f(s)ds$. Though similar to the previous one, I find that L'Hospital no longer works(yielding $\frac{f(t)}{-t^{-2}-\lambda t^{-1}}$). Is there any method to deal with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you mean it seems to be impossible to prove it with $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}f(t)=0$?

Comment: Actually no, we only need $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0$! Rewrite the integral as $\dfrac{t\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}f(s)\,ds-\int_0^tse^{-\lambda s}f(s)\,ds}{e^{-\lambda t}}$ and use L'Hopital twice.

Comment: Wow, how tricky! Thank you!